# img http referer

Tags: php, http

When opening an image (thru `<img>` tag) using any of the major browsers the HTTP referer header is sent. I was trying setting src attribute to some https:// url (valid certificate, was hoping that going from secured to unsecured page will blank the referer) which then was redirecting to the target page (by Location header) and few other "methods", nothing seems to be working... any ideas please?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Can you clarify?

Comment: And what is the deeper reasoning behind this. What do you need this for?

Comment: @pekka I want to blank the referer

Comment: but why? there doesn't seem to be any legit reason for this (not that I can think of it at least)

Comment: The only reason I can think of for doing this is in an effort to bypass a referer based anti-hotlinking system. I'm hoping that the OP has a better motive then that, but I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: HTML5 has `rel=noreferrer`, no idea if it works for images.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand, this could do the trick:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'header'  => 'Referer: http://example.com',
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

header('Content-Type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon');
echo file_get_contents($_GET['image_src'], false, $context);
```

And then in HTML:

```
<img src="/path/to/file.php?image_src=http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" alt="">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: … but make sure you get legal advice from a copyright lawyer before pointing this at third party images.

Comment: … and don't say an `ico` is `image/png` — it probably isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Or rather just save the image to your own website. Hotlinking images from different sites is generally considered *bandwidth stealing* by the netiquette.

Comment: Just saving the image to your website is usually considered copyright infringement. Sometimes hotlinking is too.

Comment: Not neccessarily. If you did your *due diligence* and could not find or contact the copyright holder then you can use it (you will be no subject to statutory charges). Of course if you make money on it they are eligible for the market value of their property. AFAIK

Comment: Copyright law varies from location to location. You really need to involve a lawyer if you even think about going down this route.